# Fetch data in background and display in UI

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm using volley to fetch data using `volley` and display in User Interface, and it takes time to load the data. What i want to happen is, I want to fetch the data in background during the splash screen or loading screen and display it in User `interface`. I want the fetching part to be done in another `activity` and it should be a background `service` and this should be called in "`main activity`" to populate the fields.

Comment: use Asynctask or threads or AsyncTaskLoader ,

Comment: Use  `MVVM` pattern or `Rxandroid`, it will help you in reactive programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). So the process goes like that:

- In [onPreExecute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#onPreExecute()) you can show a ProgresDialog or a ProgresBar to visualize your loading process
- in [doInBackground(Params...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params...)) you start loading your data
- and in [onPostExecute(Result)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#onPostExecute(Result)) you display your data in UI and hide your ProgresDialog/ProgresBar.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) of AsyncTask usage.

Do it like this:

```
private class LoadDataBaseData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Start loading your data 

        return "Data loaded";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       //Update your UI with data you loaded/start your activity with loaded data

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is i don't want to display any ProgressBar . when i click a button it shows updating and displays the data . the delay is 5 seconds. all i want to do is , when app starts , start loading the data in another activity and when the button is pressed display the data acquired instantly . No delay. Do the fetching part in background.

Comment: You can still do that with AsyncTask, ProgresBar/Dialog is just optional so it blocks UI for the time that data is loading. Use AsyncTask to load it, like I told you and just don't use any ProgresBars. You can start your AsyncTask OnCreate or OnStart and it should be OK.

Comment: I added an example that would suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

> use AsyncTask like that

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
   {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
       //do your work here 


        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        progressBar.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "message...");
        progressBar.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
    {
    }
}
```